# How to create a video stream with Gstreamer without RTP?

Tags: udp, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am trying to create a simple UDP video stream with Gstreamer1.0. 
The problem is that for the purpose of my project I need to be able to have a vanilla UDP stream but almost all the tutorials I was able to find have RTP enabled.
So I would like to translate this simple stream:

Player:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 !  application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264,payload=96 !  rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 !  autovideosink
```

Server:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src !  video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 !  x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay !  udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to translate this simple example in UDP only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline you stated above, at the sender's side I do not see any use of `rtp`. Ideally `rtpjpegpay` should have been used at the sender's side, which is then depayed at the receiver using `rtpjpegdepay`. 
Have you tried the same pipelines, without UDP. It would complain you that the packet size at `udpsink` is more than the buffer. You will need `rtpxpay` to fragment the video stream into rtp packets.

In case you do not need rtp, try sending the stream directly but with a limit on the buffer size at the `udpsink`. This can also result in increased delay in rendering video, some packets getting lost, etc.  Try experimenting with different values for the buffer sizes/packet size on `udpsink`. Unfortunately `udpsink` does not provide direct control on configuring these sizes. So you may have to find out other ways.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I edited my post to the right script! May I also ask you why would it delay the video rendering? I am trying to have a stream over vanilla `UDP` packets so it will have less delay for the stream as gstreamer will not need to order the packets but of course with the trade of quality, isn't it the case ?

Comment: I have no idea how a vanilla UDP stream works, but if you manage to send each video frame in one UDP packet correctly, and if the order is maintained - then you might  see acceptable delay.  You cannot guarantee the order of packet reception in normal UDP atleast, that's where RTP comes handy since it introduces sequencing of UDP packets, which can then be used at the receiving side to reorder.